# How to enable WinForms GridView columns in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form, I want to `add Permission()` like below:

```
 DataRow[] dr2 = AppConfiguration.permission.Select("MenuNameTrim = '" + this.Name + "' AND IsCanDelete = True");
 if (dr2.Length > 0)
 {
     dgvList.Columns[5].Visible = true;
 } 
 else 
 {
     dgvList.Columns[5].Visible = false;
 }
```

**I want to enable some of the grid view columns in a form according to the permissions that i set.**

Comment: Your question is not clear - do you want to enable/disable any grid column or just hide it? Please try debugging/stepping through code. Is it throwing any error? Please provide more details.

Comment: It seems , Your code is right to visible true or false to particular column of datatable...can you post more code so that people can understand

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow[] dr2 = AppConfiguration.permission.Select("MenuNameTrim = '" + this.Name + "' AND IsCanDelete = True");
 if (dr2.Length > 0)
 {
     dgvList.Columns[5].ReadOnly= true;
 } 
 else 
 {
     dgvList.Columns[5].ReadOnly = false;
 }
```

For moew detail [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: dgvList.Columns[5].ReadOnly = false doesnt work well.Please help me.